# Update a null values in countryside column in a data frame with reference to valid countrycode column from another data frame using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have two data frames: Disaster, CountryInfo
Disaster has a column country code which has some null values
for example:
Disaster:

```
 1.**Country**   - **Country_code** 
 2.India         - Null         
 3.Afghanistan   - AFD
 4.India         - IND
 5.United States - Null
```

CountryInfo:

```
0.**CountryName**   - **ISO** 
1.India             - IND
2.Afganistan        - AFD
3.United States     - US
```

I need to fill the country code with reference to the country name.Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `map` with a `Series`.

With this approach all values are overwritten not only non `NaN`.

```
# Test data
disaster = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['India', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'United States'],
                             'Country_code': [np.nan, 'AFD', 'IND', np.nan]})
country = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['India', 'Afghanistan', 'United States'],
                         'Country_code': ['IND', 'AFD', 'US']})

# Transforming country into a Series in order to be able to map it directly
country_se = country.set_index('Country').loc[:, 'Country_code']
# Map
disaster['Country_code'] = disaster['Country'].map(country_se)

print(disaster)
#          Country Country_code
# 0          India          IND
# 1    Afghanistan          AFD
# 2          India          IND
# 3  United States           US
```

You can filter on `NaN` if you do not want to overwrite all values.

```
disaster.loc[pd.isnull(disaster['Country_code']), 
             'Country_code'] = disaster['Country'].map(country_se)
```

Comment: @Bharath Hello, could you write sentences please. I do not understand your comment. Thanks.

Comment: X Hi, Can you help with the below [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39706194/update-a-null-values-in-countrycode-column-in-a-data-frame-by-matching-substring). Thanks