# Update a null values in countrycode column in a data frame by matching substring of country name using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have two data frames: Disaster, CountryInfo Disaster has a column country code which has some null values for example:

Disaster:

```
 1.**Country**              - **Country_code** 
 2.India                    - Null         
 3.Afghanistan (the)        - AFD
 4.India                    - IND
 5.United States of America - Null
```

CountryInfo:

```
0.**CountryName**   - **ISO** 
1.India             - IND
2.Afganistan        - AFD
3.United States     - US
```

Expected Result

```
          Country Country_code
 0          India          IND
 1    Afghanistan          AFD
 2          India          IND
 3  United States           US
```

I need to fill the country code with reference to the substring of the country name.Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. You need to change the column names with `rename` so that both `dataframes` have the same column names. Then, the `difflib` module and its `get_close_matches` method can be used to do a fuzzy match and replace of `Country` names. Then it is a simple matter of merging the `dataframes`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import difflib

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country' : ['India', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'United States of America'],
                        'Country_code' : ['Null', 'AFD', 'IND', 'Null']})
df1
                    Country Country_code
0                     India         Null
1               Afghanistan          AFD
2                     India          IND
3  United States of America         Null

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Country' : ['India', 'Afghanistan', 'India', 'United States'],
                    'ISO' : ['IND', 'AFD', 'IND', 'USA']})
df2
          Country ISO
0          India  IND
1    Afghanistan  AFD
2          India  IND
3  United States  USA

df2.rename(columns={'ISO' : 'Country_code'}, inplace=True)
df2
         Country Country_code
0          India          IND
1    Afghanistan          AFD
2          India          IND
3  United States          USA
```

The following code will change the `Country` column in `df2` with the names in the `Country` column in `df1` that provide the closest match. This is a way of performing a kind of "fuzzy join" on the substrings.

```
df1['Country'] = df1.Country.map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df2.Country)[0])
df1
         Country Country_code
0          India         Null
1    Afghanistan          AFD
2          India          IND
3  United States         Null
```

Now you can simply `merge` the `dataframes`, which will update missing `Country_code` rows in `df1`.

```
df1.merge(df2, how='right', on=['Country', 'Country_code'])

         Country Country_code
0    Afghanistan          AFD
1          India          IND
2          India          IND
3  United States          USA
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but  country names are not same in both the dataframes.I need to use the substring of the values to match the country names. For example United States of America should match United states by taking the substring United States and have to bring the country code accordingly.

Comment: Got it. You need to import the difflib module then run this code df2.Country.map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1.Country)[0]) (I have edited my original answer). This will find the closest match between the Country column in df2 and df1 and return. . You can then join the data frames.

Comment: Sorry, it is not working properly. It returns 'Tunisia' for 'Russia' and it doesn't want to change my country names in disaster data frame.But when i try using the below code to match the country name `countryinfo[countryinfo['ISOen_proper'].str.contains("Russia")]` but it returns the whole data frame and it couldn't apple pass the data frame here .Can someone tell me how to implement this functionality for the whole data frame and map the iso code to disaster data frame.

Comment: I fixed some of the above code - try it again to see if it works. Fuzzy matching is inherently imperfect, so it may return some incorrect matches. If you are still struggling check out the fuzzywuzzy module.